# Perfect Number In C

Tags: c, perfect-numbers

I need to write a C program to find the Perfect Number..

```
main()
{
    int n=1000,sum = 0;
    for(int num = 1; num <= n; num++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < num; i++)
        {
            if(!(num%i))
            {
                sum+=i;
            }
        }
        if(sum == num)
            printf("\n%d",num);
    }
}
```

`if(!(num%i))`  -  This is d line I do not understand.

If there is any other simple method do please suggest me

Comment: % operator is for remainder from dividing left side by right side
1 % 3 = 1; 2 % 3 = 2; 3 % 3 = 0; 4 % 3 = 1; 5 % 3 = 2; 6 % 3 = 0;

Comment: What is a Perfect Number? `42`? :) And you wrote code that you don't understand? How come?

Comment: You read it as `if not remainder of num / i`.

Comment: @Felix: a number that is the sum of its divisors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(!(num%i))` simply means `if( (num%i) == 0 )`

Comment: Also, as a matter of style, just write it out like ykatchou did.  The clarity is worth the extra 5 or so characters typed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a more efficient way to find perfect numbers, you might want to read the [Wikipedia page on perfect numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number). In it you will find that there are no known odd perfect numbers (and using your method you are not going to find any) and that all even perfect numbers are of the form:

`2^(p - 1)*(2^p - 1)` where `2^p - 1` is prime and therefore `p` is a prime. Thus if you want to find even perfect numbers check the primality of `2^p - 1` for all primes `p`, if so `2^(p - 1)*(2^p - 1)` is perfect.

If you just want to find a few small perfect numbers using a simple loop you can make your approach more efficient by noting that if `i` divides `num`, so does `num / i`. That is, you only have to loop up until the square root of `num` and add pairs `i` and `num / i` to `sum`. Note that if `num` is square, the square root of `num` has to be added only once.

Note that if you calculate `sum` in this way, it's value will be `2 * num` for perfect numbers, not `num`.

Comment: @Harish, See here for more http://mersenne.org/ and note that your program is going to take a long, long time to run however you do it if you want more than the first dozen perfect numbers or so.

Answer (score 1):

`num % i` means "num [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) i"; it returns the reminder of the division of the numbers (hence, a number between `0` and `i-1`).

In C, 0 is false and all other numbers are true, so `!(num % i)` tests if "num modulo i" is zero, or in plain math-speak, if num is evenly divisible by i.

Answer (score 0):

In very simple way, the `if(!(num%i))` code checks that if the value of num is divided by i and it returns if remainder is 0 or not...Hence the the modulus operator % is used here to find the remainder.. this piece of code is similar to `if(num % i==0)`.
if it returns true then the value of i should be added with sum. Finally if the value of sum is equal to the value of num, the number is perfect and the number is displayed!