# How to check if array elements are perfect numbers?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program where the array size is not entered by the user,but the elements are, until 0 is entered.Now I want to check for each element which one is a perfect number,for that I have to do the sum of the divisors.Problem is I can't manage to do the sum of divisors for each element in the array,instead it adds all the divisors of all the elements in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 1000, i, j, sum = 0;
    int v[n];

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
        if (v[i] == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        for (j = 1; j < v[i]; j++)
        {
            if (v[i] % j == 0)
            {
                printf("%d", j);
                sum = sum + j;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n%d",sum);

    return 0;
}
```

[**OUTPUT**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gctVz.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by a "Perfect" number?

Comment: Reset `sum` to zero before starting the search for factors of each array element.

Comment: @AdanVivero: [Perfect number.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perfect Number In C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554351/perfect-number-in-c)

Comment: @Renat no because it's not using arrays,I can do this without using arrays .

Comment: A good design here would be to write a function that takes a single integer as an argument, and tests whether it is a perfect number.  Then your `sum` will naturally be a local variable of that function, initialized on every call, and you would never have had this bug in the first place.

Comment: More generally, define every variable in the narrowest scope where it is needed.  Even with the code as it is, you do not need `sum` anywhere outside the `i` loop, so you could have defined and initialized it in that block, and again avoided this bug.

Comment: I got it thanks @NateEldredge and Eric

Answer (score 1):

Brut force check can be very expensive. It is faster to build the table of perfect numbers using Euclides formula and then simple check if the number is perfect.

```
static unsigned long long getp(int x)
{
    return (2ULL << (x - 2)) * ((2ULL << (x - 1)) - 1);
}

int isperfect(unsigned long long x)
{
    const int primes[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 31};
    static unsigned long long array[sizeof(primes) / sizeof(primes[0])];
    int result = 0;

    if(!array[0])
    {
        for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(primes) / sizeof(primes[0]); index++)
        {
            array[index] = getp(primes[index]);
        }
    }
    for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(primes) / sizeof(primes[0]); index++)
    {
        if(x == array[index])
        {
            result = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The array of perfect numbers is build only one time on the first function call.

And some usage (your code a bit modified)

```
int main(void)
{
    size_t n = 1000, i;
    unsigned long long v[n];

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%llu", &v[i]);
        if (v[i] == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("%llu is %s perfect number\n", v[i], isperfect(v[i]) ? "" : "not");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/exMs345xb